# Cartoon about future ice age

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember a short cartoon series from the 70s set in a future ice age. I think it was shown within another programme, ( for some reason I thought it was *The Banana Splits*!)

I recall the story being about some people (children?) travelling across a frozen continent in order to find some kind of sanctuary or city. It was set in the future, possibly after a nuclear winter.

But I've been unable to find any trace of it in that). This has been bugging me for years, any ideas?

Comment: What else do you remember about the show?  Even tiny details can help.  What country did you watch it in?  Who were the main characters?

Comment: I would suggest checking out the link below I've provided below.  This site lists and show images of all sorts of cartoon shows and comics that are either "stone age" or "ice age".  There are quite a few TV cartoon shows in the 1960s and 1970s that may fit what you are looking for (such as Mightor or Valley of the Dinosaurs) :  http://www.ancientcraft.co.uk/fun/characters.html

Comment: I recall the story being about some people (children?) travelling across a frozen continent in order to find some kind of sanctuary or city. It was set in the future, possibly after a nuclear winter. Sorry can't remember much else

Comment: I very vaguely remember something along these lines. There was one last city/arcology which was hemmed in by glaciers. At some point the glaciers broke through. The animation was shots of drawings, with zooming in for dramatic bits, rather than conventional frame-by-frame animation. I was in the UK and this would have been some time in the early 70s.

Comment: @Paul Johnson - yes, I vividly remember the images of this series too. I was captivated by it, but it seemed to end prematurely. The score was very powerful and it conjured a very urgent sense of drama.

Comment: Thanks - I was beginning to think I was going mad (short story idea) I thought I was the only person who remembered this. As you describe the only additional details I seem to recall was that it was part of another show (in the same way Bleep and Booster were in Blue Peter or the shows in the Banana Splits) You've misunderstood if you think this is about the historic ice age - this was set in the future And it scared me!